# Isolated Storage - How to read the appended data

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have a `Game application(WP8)`, where we are saving the scores of multiple attampts and showing it to user.

I have a Object with fields noOfStonesPicked and noOfFruitsPicked.

Here is my code:

```
MyTopic topicObj = new MyTopic ();

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                Test mt = new Test();
                mt.noOfStonesPicked = 12;
                mt.noOfFruitsPicked= 20;
                topicObj.Stats.Add(mt);
                }                

WritetestTopicState(topicObj);
```

Now 3 attempts with each one having `noOfStonesPicked -12 and noOfFruitsPicked - 20`

Now i have saving this like :

```
public static void WritetestTopicState(MyTopic topic)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile("12.xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTopic));
                        serializer.Serialize(sw, topic);
                        serializer = null;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Now how can i retrive these values and display ?

**EDIT**

This is what i have tried:

```
public static MyTopic ReadMockTestTopicState()
        {
            MyTopic topic = null;
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    // Read application settings. 
                    if (isoStore.FileExists("11.xml"))
                    {
                        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("12.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
                            {
                                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTopic));
                                topic = (MyTopic)serializer.Deserialize(SR);
                                serializer = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If setting does not exists return default setting.
                        topic = new MyTopic();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return topic;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTopic));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
_myTopic = (MyTopic)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

This should be enough for deserializing, **If your `MyTopic` object is properly serializable**, I mean if properties of the MyTopic object are properly attributed for xml serialization.

Comment: Please see my edit, i have tried that, first time when i run the it will store and retrive 3 values, next time when i run it throws me error that `Unexpected XML declaration`.

Comment: That means you have some problem in your MyTopic object. Probably the properties of the MyTopic object are not properly attributed for xml serialization.